# Shopify API fields not updated

Tags: api, shopify

I am using a Private Application to update some fields of my products.

The calls are going through just fine (and returning 200 OK), however, none of the fields passed is actually being updated, and I am being returned the old product field values.

```
PUT https://MYKEY:MYPASS@MYSHOP.myshopify.com/admin/products/NNNNNNNN.json
{"product":{"id": NNNNNNNN,"title":"Product Name"}}
```

Returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
{"product": {title: 'OLD TITLE'}, .... }
```

PS: I am using CURL, and I can read the products. Just can't update them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. You have to set `'content-type': 'application/json'` in your request, which is not really documented in the API Docs.